# Die Wendung "... nicht nur ..., sondern (?) ..."

Tags: usage, grammaticality, style

Beim Verfassen eines SEO-Textes habe ich die Wendung

> **a)** ... nicht nur ..., sondern *ebenso* ...

verwendet. Der Korrektor wandte ein, es müsse

> **b)** ... nicht nur ..., sondern *auch* ...

heißen. Da die Korrektur anonym ist, kann ich den Korrektor leider nicht fragen, warum er zwingend nur **b)** für richtig hält. Ich bezweifle nicht, dass **b)** häufiger vorkomme als **a)**. Ich bezweifle allerdings die alleinige Richtigkeit von **b)**.

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, wer, wieso, wo eine solche Regel aufgestellt haben sollte. Weder aus grammatikalischer noch aus stilistischer Sicht erkenne ich bei **a)** ein Problem. Da man ja manchmal betriebsblind ist, habe ich mich dennoch auf die Suche begeben - erfolglos! Zwar kennt [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nicht_nur_%E2%80%A6_sondern_auch) nur die Variante **b)**, bei [openthesaurus.de](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/nicht%20nur%20%28...%29%20sondern%20auch) ist **a)** aber zumindest als Synonym verzeichnet. Bei Nietzsche (*Die fröhliche Wissenschaft*, [381](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Nietzsche,+Friedrich/Die+fr%C3%B6hliche+Wissenschaft/F%C3%BCnftes+Buch.+Wir+Furchtlosen/381.+Zur+Frage+der+Verst%C3%A4ndlichkeit)) findet man

> Man will **nicht nur** verstanden werden, wenn man schreibt, **sondern ebenso** gewiß auch *nicht* verstanden werden.

Weiß jemand mehr dazu? Kennt vielleicht jemand eine Quellenangabe, eine Regel, eine Begründung hinsichtlich Stils - irgendetwas ...?

Comment: Ich halte auch ausschließlich b für richtig, kann aber keine andere Regel als den tatsächlichen Gebrauch dieser Wendung nennen. Vergleiche: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sondern+ebenso%2C+sondern+auch&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csondern%20ebenso%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csondern%20auch%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ist es wichtig, wenn Du doch ohnehin für Maschinen und nicht für Menschen schreibst?

Comment: Ich finde b) idiomatischer.

Comment: Ich würde eine Formulierung nicht verwenden, weil Nietzsche sie verwendet hat. Seine Werke haben schon ein paar Jahrzehnte auf dem Buckel. Ausserdem hat das Nietzsche-Zitat das "auch" nur etwas später.

Comment: @Robert, Sie haben das missverstanden: Ich habe die Formulierung nicht von Nietzsche entlehnt, sondern sie entstammt meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl. Ich benutze sie sogar recht häufig; bislang hatte ich auch keinen Grund an ihrer Richtigkeit zu zweifeln. Das Zitat von Nietzsche habe ich erst im Zuge meiner Recherche gefunden, um zu zeigen, dass auch andere diese Formulierung verwenden. Weitere Beispiele gibt es übrigens hier: https://www.dwds.de/r?q=%22sondern+ebenso%22&from=&h=1&corpus=kern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Als Beschreibung für *»ebenso«* führt der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ebenso) an:

> in ebenderselben Weise, in der gleichen Weise, geradeso [sehr],
>   genauso [sehr]

*»Ebenso«* kannst du dann verwenden, wenn du es in deinem Satz durch einen der genannten Ausdrücke ersetzen könntest.

Bei der Konstruktion *»nicht nur (...), sondern auch«* dürfte das Ersetzen von *»auch«* durch *»ebenso«* im Allgemeinen kein Problem sein. Darauf deutet auch diese Quelle hin:

> Als [Pleonasmen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pleonasmus) gelten auch die überflüssigen Häufungen sinngleicher
>   oder sinnverwandter Wörter (Tautologie): bereits schon, leider zu meinem Bedauern, höchstens nur, **ebenso auch**, einander gegenseitig, lediglich nur.
>
> <sub>Quelle: Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch (1998)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

"Nicht nur ... sondern ebenso ..." funktioniert für mich nicht richtig und erinnert mich frappant an die Sprechweise von "Dupond & Dupont" (*Schulze & Schultze*) in *Tintin* ("Tim und Struppi"), deren "Running Gag" es ist, das sie ständig "nicht nur x, sondern sogar x" sagen (x beides Mal dasselbe).

"Nicht nur x, sondern ..." bereitet den Hörer darauf vor, dass als nächstes etwas die erste Aussage erweiterndes, steigerndes kommen soll. Da passt beim besten Willen kein "ebenso" dazu (siehe Begriffserklärung des Duden in der anderen Antwort), weil dieses eben *dasselbe* wie x weiterführt.

Comment: Den letzten Absatz verstehe ich nicht, zumal mich der Duden eher bestärkt. So lässt sich "_Das betrifft nicht nur A, sondern **auch/ebenso/genauso/gleichermaßen** B._" nach meinem Sprachverständnis einwandfrei durch "_Das betrifft nicht nur A, sondern **in der gleichen Weise** B._" ersetzen. Ähnliches gilt beispielsweise für "_Das lässt ich nicht nur auf A anwenden, sondern **auch/ebenso/genauso/gleichermaßen** auf B._" Wieso sollte "beim besten Willen kein" **ebenso** - oder eine der anderen Formen, die ich noch hinzugefügt habe - dazu passen?